# Find the projection of $b$ onto the column space of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & -1 \\
   -2 & 4
  \end{array} } \right]
$ and $b = 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1  \\
   2 \\
   7
  \end{array} } \right]
$

I use the formula $p = A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}b$

$A^{T}A = 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   6 & -8 \\
   -8 & 18 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

$(A^{T}A)^{-1} = \frac{1}{44} 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   18 & 8 \\
   8 & 6 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

$A^{T}b =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   -11 \\
   27 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

Putting everything together,

$p =  \frac{1}{44}\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & -1 \\
   -2 & 4
  \end{array} } \right] \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   18 & 8 \\
   8 & 6 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   -11 \\
   27 \\
  \end{array} } \right]= \frac{1}{44}\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   92 \\
   -56 \\
260  \end{array} } \right]$

Which is completely different from the book's answer $p=(3,0,6)$. Where did I go wrong?
Also, if the question asked for a projection of $b$ onto the row space of $A$, would I take the transpose of $A$ first, say let $B = A^{T}$ then use the formula $p = B(B^{T}B)^{-1}B^{T}b$?

Comment: Maybe the book is wrong.

Comment: Just, double check your calculations.

Comment: Your answer is correct; the matrix $\frac{1}{11} \begin{pmatrix} 10 & 3 & 1\\3 & 2 & -3\\ 1 & -3 & 10\end{pmatrix}$ is the projection matrix onto the column space of A.